# Azure Application Gateway HTTP Settings Backend Port Resets to 80

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

In the Azure Portal, I have created the following Application Gateway with the Backend Pools, Rules, Listeners, and HTTP Settings below.  I want the HTTP Settings to be configured with the backend ports below and have placed the settings in the backend port fields numerous times.  However, when I save the setting, Azure resets the port to 80.  Has anyone run into this issue before?  Please provide any guidance that you may have on how to resolve the issue.

AppGateway

Backend Pools

1. Pool1 - 2 servers listening on port 80
2. Pool2 - 1 server listening on port 8080
3. Pool3 - 1 server listening on port 8777

Rules

1. Rule1 - Listener1 - HTTP1
2. Rule2 - Listener2 - HTTP2
3. Rule3 - Listener3 - HTTP3

Listeners

1. Listener1 - multisite - port 80 - domain #1
2. Listener2 - multisite - port 80 - domain #2
3. Listener3 - multisite - port 80 - domain #3

HTTP Settings

1. HTTP1 - port 80 - backend port 80
2. HTTP2 - port 8080 - backend port 8080
3. HTTP3 - port 8777 - backend port 8777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I ran into this issue with the portal a couple of weeks ago - going into the edit panel displays the port field value to 80, **even though the underlying stored value is different**.

**If this goes unnoticed when editing a different field, it will update the http settings with the potentially incorrect '80' default.**

Therefore if you specify your desired value either in the portal, Az PS, CLI or ARM deployment it will use the port you set.  It's just that edit panel doesn't seem to display the underlying value.

Comment: Thank you, Oliver!  I thought I was missing something.